# How to have a straight line uv

Tags: uv

I have uv map. It is similar to O shape.

[image]

[image]

With the textool addon. On clicking the Rectify it creates C shape.

[image]

I want to have a straight line uv without any bending or twist. **Without apply any modifier used.** A straight line.

Any suggestion or help how can i make it.

Comment: Could you please manually chop up say the C result above and add an illustration to question  of what the expected _"straight line"_ result would look like?

Comment: @batFINGER https://imgur.com/a/oE1ib4S like this a straight line uv.

Comment: If you don't mind marking two seams under the top corners of the loop, you can use the UV Squares addon (supplied in Blender) and click 'UV to grid with respect to shape' to give you two parallel lines of UVs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you can have a straight line with the current topology, what you could do in the *UV Editor* is rip the 2 horizontal rows, rotate them 90° and stick them to the vertical.

Or you can change your topology, going from that:

[image]

to that:

[image]

then select all, select an active face, press <kbd>U</kbd> > *Reset*, then <kbd>U</kbd> again and > *Follow Active Quads*, and it will give a straight line.

Comment: Thanks. that a good suggestion. It work